# Stationary Blender particles on rotating circular plane not rotating as if following planes rotation

Tags: particles, normals, geometry

I want my particles to rotate as the circular plane beneath them rotates in order to give the impression of ships or cars travelling in a circle. My particles normals are not orienting in the direction of feigned movement.

[image: Particles on a rotating circular plane]

I tried the following:

1. Delete everything in initial scene
2. Create Mesh - Circle
3. Edit mode with circle selected, Extrude, Scale
4. Object mode, Create Mesh - Cone
5. Scale down cone
6. Select circle, insert rotation keyframe (Will insert 0 value keyframe at frame 1)
7. In timeline, click frame 359
8. Rotate circle 359 degrees on the Z access and insert keyframe (Check for full rotation)
9. Select circle and add particle system modifier
10. In particle properties, select hair
11. In particle properties under render, select cone as the instance object
12. In particle properties, click advanced and enable the "Rotation" checkbox
13. In rotation change orientation axis to "Normal"/"Normal-Tangent"

I tried UV unwrapping the circular plane but nothing happened. I've tried seemingly every possible orientation and applying transforms. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you can kind of "fake it" by building a mesh circle like this and  extrude it.

If you then set the phase to 0.5 you get what you want.

You can hide this circle and adapt it to your needs.

[image]

[image]

if you need further details, let me know.

[image]